# Как сделать не обработку исключений ошибкой компиляции?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022

Можно ли сделать не обработку в `catch` исключений ошибкой компиляции ?

Comment: что значит "сделать не обработку"?

Comment: @iikuzmychov метод может вызвать исключение, я проигнорировал обработку этих исключений, получил ошибку компиляции. Я же должен их обработать на месте или отправить на уровень выше, вот хочу ошибку компиляции.

Comment: _или отправить на уровень выше_ - ну вот они и отправляются на уровень выше.

Comment: В Java так сделали. Теперь локти кусают.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov хм, если не оберну в `try` `catch` - уйдёт на уровень выше ?

Comment: Если исключение не поймано в catch, то оно пробрасывается выше. Если и там не обработано - ещё выше. Пока не дойдёт до самого верха - тогда приложение крашнется. В этом и мякотка исключений, что их нельзя не обработать, в отличие от кодов возврата. Это быстро обнаружится и будет исправлено.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov понял - нужно эту тему снова перечитать) у меня всё крашилось на месте и я думал если не обработаю на месте - всему конец) А и за лени замечал что много не обрабатываю на месте. Просто на уровень выше я передавал с помощью `throw new` какой нибудь `exeption("", ex)`

Comment: Можно, конечно, попробовать статические анализаторы натравить на код. PVS-studio и т. п. Они могут выдавать такие сообщения, но они не могут знать, на каком уровне разработчик хочет обработать исключение.